# Distributed transaction aborted by MSDTC

Tags: sql-server

how to resolve the error 8522 in sql server 2005.

I'm working with two servers.every time when i have to work i have to fetch live 
data from the server that is at remote place.
I fetch that live data onmy local server and work.

form last threemonth it was working fine but now its giving following  error.

Distributed transaction aborted by MSDTC.

Comment: serverfault.com is a better fit

Comment: @Remus: not convinced of that enough to vote for that though?

Comment: then sir ....providethe solution for that.

Comment: @Anthony not sure how you do that. Vote for close?

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information in your question to be very helpful.  Some code/description of the process would result in better answers.

Here a link from Google that may be of use:

http://blogs.conchango.com/paulmcmillan/archive/2005/10/17/2277.aspx